# SQl Server multiple rows group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Lets suppose i got those 2 tables :

```
ID  Time  UserId
1   08:00   55
2   08:00   22
3   08:00   04
4   09:00   17
5   11:00   11
...etc...

UserId  Name
01      Brian
02      Francis
03      David
...etc...
```

My wanted results are:

```
Hours(distinct)   Name
08:00             Franck,Michelle,Damian
09:00             Indiana, Robert
```

In fact , i want all the distinct hours to be listed in the first column and all the names of users listed as one row. I tried this query :

> SELECT   distinct convert (varchar(25),Time ,120) ,test = STUFF ((
>   SELECT ',' + Name From T2 WHERE T1.UserId=T2.Id FOR XML PATH('')),
>   1,1,'')    FROM T1 group BY Time

the query works without the group by but it trigger an error with it "  Column 'UserId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Any idea ?

Comment: Get rid of `group BY Time` part.

Comment: If i get rid of group by , i just got a single name for each row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML aggregation must only depend on columns listed in GROUP BY, `time` in your case

```
SELECT distinct convert (varchar(25),Time ,120) 
 ,test = STUFF (( 
    SELECT ',' + Name 
    FROM T2 
    WHERE T2.UserId IN (
         SELECT T3.UserID 
         FROM T1 AS T3
         WHERE T3.time=T0.time)
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'') 
FROM T1 as T0 
GROUP BY Time
```

Comment: NEER beat you at it but your solution is as smooth as him. Thanks a lot :m).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.Time
    STUFF(
        (SELECT
            ',' + T2.Name
        FROM
            Table1 T1 INNER JOIN 
            Table2 T2 ON T1.UserId = T2.UserId
        WHERE
            T1.Time = T.Time
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') A
FROM
    Table1 T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  t1.time, t1.userid, t2.name
FROM tab1 t1
JOIN tab2 t2
  ON t1.userid = t2.userid)
SELECT
  c.time,
  (STUFF((SELECT ',' + d.name
  FROM cte d
  WHERE c.time = d.time
  FOR xml PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS Test
FROM cte c
GROUP BY c.time
```